# web3.eth.accounts.sign 'K' generation

Tags: web3js, web3.py, ecdsa

I have been searching for the actual implementation of the `web3.eth.accounts.sign` to find out how the random variable k is generated. But I could not find the implementation of the method `web3.eth.accounts.sign`. I am new to JS, please bear with me :D

Any idea?

Comment: From [geth's implementation of Sign function](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/release/1.10/crypto/secp256k1/secp256.go#L69) they uses RFC 6979 to create deterministic signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are random variables Ethereum message signing, as it has to be deterministic.

For the example of the implementation of [Ethereum message signing with private key, see eth-lib library source code](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/eth-lib/blob/master/src/account.js).

Comment: I don't think "it has to be", non-deterministic signature works as well. It can be considered "weak" if randomness used is weak.

Check heading "ECDSA Math" here: https://cypherpunks-core.github.io/ethereumbook/06transactions.html .

RFC 6979 "can" be used for deterministic signatures

Answer (score 0):

Any random private key (32 byte), that is valid on ECC (key < curve order), should be valid. However, random key [must](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-magic-of-digital-signatures-on-ethereum-98fe184dc9c7) [be](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347058250_An_Improvement_of_ECDSA_Weak_Randomness_in_Blockchain) "cryptographically random", default random generators of programming languages might not be enough.

> When k is not sufficiently random, or when the value is not secret, it’s possible to calculate the private key using two different signatures (“fault attack”)

Pseudo-code for signing can be [found here](https://cypherpunks-core.github.io/ethereumbook/06transactions.html). If `AWS KMS` is used to sign transactions, [it uses](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part2-use-aws-kms-to-securely-manage-ethereum-accounts/) non-deterministic signatures.

You can also [make](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-magic-of-digital-signatures-on-ethereum-98fe184dc9c7) signature output deterministic:

> These deterministic signatures use the RFC 6979 standard, which describes how you can generate a secure value for k based on the private key and message (or hash).

Discussion [blog about](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2022/01/) deterministic/non-deterministic ECDSA.